# How to modify the corrupted Microsoft SDKs header file ShlObj.h

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, winapi

In my development computer, the ShlObj.h file got modified.

The corrupted  ShlObj.h code is as below. I need to use the macro `CSIDL_APPDATA` in my code.

```
#define CSIDL_APPDATA  F                 0x001a        // <user name>\Application Data
```

(File Path : c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\ShlObj.h)

I can't modify the file ShlObj.h manually. It seems that I do not have the permissions required to modify the file.

Should I repair or reinstall the SDK?

Environment: Win7 64 bit/Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I could be wrong but I wouldn't expect repair to have enough information to be able to fix your problem.  I think you'll need to reinstall.  OTOH repair is quick - why not try it and see what happens?  It could be that even reinstall won't fix it, you might have to uninstall and then reinstall - depends on how literal reinstall is.  Obviously someone/thing has permission to modify the file - if you have administrator priviledge you should be able to go in and fix the file manually.  But then again maybe other files have also been corrupted so maybe reinstall is safer.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. It was an access issue. My user has admin privilege, but some access was missing, IT security team helped me. Your suggestion was my solution, I  am wondering how I can accept your solution